# Editing properties of object's properties using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to edit the properties of an object's properties while looping through said object's properties. Ok, that was hard to get out of my head! Hopefully a code example will help here!

```
MyObject object = new MyObject();
foreach (PropertyInfo propInfo in typeof(MyObject).GetProperties())
{
    if (propInfo.PropertyType.ToString().Contains("System"))
    {
        continue;
    }
    foreach (PropertyInfo subPropInfo in propInfo.PropertyType.GetProperties())
    {
         if (subPropInfo.PropertyType.ToString().Contains("System"))
         {
              continue;
         }
         else
         {
            // Set the value here
         }
    }
}
```

I can use `SetValue(object, "value")` in the first loop of object but I can't work out how to use it in the nested loop. Is there a way to do this or am I completely going about this the wrong way?

Comment: which object do you want to set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of the sub property you get the value of the outer property and use that as the "object" for the sub property's Info object:

```
var subPropertyValue = subPropInfo.GetValue(propInfo.GetValue(obj, null), null);
```

To set it; same idea:

```
subPropInfo.SetValue(propInfo.GetValue(obj, null), someValue);
```